# SF book about a spaceship captain and female officer who survive a crash landing on a jungle planet and are hunted by an invisible alien predator

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space, military-sf

I am looking for the title of a SF book about a male and female space officer who survived a spaceship crash on an alien planet where everyone of their crew is dead and an invisible alien tries to hunt them down.

Avoiding the alien and trying to get back home brings the characters together as they race across the jungle planet, where they find out that the alien hunting them is not native to this planet. The alien had already killed the entire planet's original alien population, but they left behind instructions that could help the characters in defeating this predator. If they were to procreate, then the alien planet would give them powers to defeat this predator.

While on Earth, the female character's older brother was a Lieutenant of a commanding ship and had realised that he hadn't heard from his sister's ship and tries to find out what had happened and tracks them to their last location.

I had read this books a few years ago and can remember that it had a brown cover, I think, but I can't seem remember the name or the author. Much help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you be a bit more specific about the range of years within which you believe you read this?

Comment: There are some similarities to E.E. "Doc" Smith's *Spacehounds of the IPC* - mainly the male and female crashing on a planet and being hunted by an alien - though I am not sure it is invisible.

Comment: This reminds me of AE Van Vogt's "Black Destroyer" from "Voyage of the Space Beagle".  Not enough details match, however. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Destroyer

Comment: @SamAzon it's funny because the two characters stranded on a planet are also in a different Van Vogt story, part of the "Fifty Suns" arc - I think "The Storm".

Comment: @LSerni Characters stranded on hostile planets are common van Vogt fare.  The same main character gets marooned (with various companions) three times in *The War Against the Rull*.

Comment: @LogicDictates I had read this book six years ago